# Math loop but solves when x is correct

Tags: loop-spaces

Is there a calculation of some sort that loops itself when for example x =1 but stops looping and solves when x is for example 5.

Comment: Please clarify the question (add some proper definitions, like what do you mean by trap?), and ideally, some wider context for this question

Comment: Are thinking about something like this ($\int{e^x\sin(x)dx}$): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Acp8PFx8180

Comment: loop-spaces is probably not the right category here either.

Comment: @YuriyS What i mean with trap: a calculation that loops when solved wrong but solved itself when example : x is wrong the hole calculation starts again but when x is right it works out.

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry for that, it's my first post on stack exchange

Comment: @Ingix not directly but I think that I can use that calculation for something else

Comment: Such problems are behind locks and bars, buried deep in the Pico Vault :-). Truly, it is unclear what you want.

Comment: @YuriyS : if x is 1 the calculation stays looping and it won't solve but when x = 13 it stops looping and it can be solved

Comment: Still no idea what you mean, maybe it's just me though. What you absolutely should do is edit *the post* with additional explanation instead of adding several comments. There's an edit button for a reason

Comment: What do you mean by "x is correct", what do you mean by "solves" and finally, what precisely do you mean by a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is more of a program (in pseudocode) than a "calculation", but it can trap itself (when $1$ is input) and can calculate $3$ (when something not $1$ is input, such as $5.$).

INPUT $x$

Label (A)

If $x=1$ GOTO (A)

If $x \neq 1$ GOTO (B)

Label (B)

OUTPUT $3$

END

Comment: You did not just use two (!) goto directives in 7 lines of code :\

Comment: Thanks! That is what i need!

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, that's sloppy. OP just wanted *something* so I'll leave it. Guess the second GOTO could be dropped, along with LABEL (B),

Comment: @coffeemath, I'm just kidding, really I quite enjoyed your answer, cheers